# Navigation to menus not working

Tags: java, selenium, testng

I have been trying and experimenting with some code involving java and Selenium webdriver and the code to click on a link does not seem to work when the mouse control is on the browser. Immediately when i remove the control, the code works fine. I'm quiet baffled by this as the other way around usually causes error. Here im trying to click on sub menus using the text visible on the screen. Have tested it both in Firefox 24 and IE.

```
HomePage homePage=new HomePage(driver); 
homePage.navigate("Tickets,Flight Tickets,Book Tickets");

public void navigate(String path){
    String navigationPath=path;


    for (String navStep: navigationPath.split(",")){
            System.out.println(navStep);
Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
          WebElement element= new WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(ExpectedConditions
                    .elementToBeClickable(By.linkText(text.trim())));
          actions.moveToElement(element).build().perform();
          element.click();
}
```

Dont know if my settings in Eclipse IDE or the system is wrong to cause this error. Some insight into this issue would really be of help.

Thanks and Regards

Sushanth.G

Answer (score 0):

can you try  the code below if your submenu pops up on hovering the mouse over main menu..

```
for (String navStep: navigationPath.split(",")){
            System.out.println(navStep);
Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
WebElement element= new WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(ExpectedConditions
                    .elementToBeClickable(By.linkText(text.trim())));
          actions.moveToElement(element).build().perform();

}
actions.click();
actions.perform();
```

Answer (score 0):

No, it does not work. Its actually clicking on the main menu but the sub menus dont open up and it fails to locate the sub menus.
Error Message obtained "Timed out after 5 seconds waiting for element to be clickable: By.linkText: Flight Tickets"

If i hover the mouse on the task bar then it works properly.

Thanks and Regards
Sushanth.G